# Flutter display firebase storage image from path

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have been reading some questions around this and I can't find anything really that is relevant to what I am trying to do, and what I am trying to do is very simple.

I have the path of an image file from Firebase Storage, say:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String fileName = prefs.getString('currentProfileImage');

StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref()
  .child(widget.currentUserUID.toString() + '/profile/' + fileName);
```

So the image file path will be something like:

```
b8sJ7cEHCFdjh46wZNp5xThbvVzz2/profile/image_picker209656937087714.jpg
```

I just want to display this image.    That's all.  How can I convert knowing the exact path to this file into an object of type Image?

Comment: It's the path inside Firebase Storage.   I don't know how to get the URL from this, if that's all I need.   I have tried to use .getDownloadURL()  with this reference and when I convert this to string all it says is "Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'"

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the image first to Firebase Storage using `putFile()`:

```
StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await storage
   .ref()
   .child(widget.currentUserUID.toString() + '/profile/' + fileName)
   .putFile(file)
   .onComplete;
```

---

Then you get the `url` of the image in Firebase Storage and save it to Firestore, for example:

```
  final String downloadUrl =
      await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection("images")
      .add({"url": downloadUrl, "name": imageName});
```

Then to display the image you can do the following:

```
body: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getImages(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                title:
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                leading: Image.network(
                    snapshot.data.documents[index].data["url"],
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              );
            });
      } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
        return Text("No data");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
),

/// code here

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getImages() {
    return fb.collection("images").getDocuments();
  }
```

`getImages()` will retrieve the data inside the collection, then `Image.network` will take the url of the image and display the image in the application.

Comment: Hi Peter.   All your talk of the URL made the solution simple in this case.   When I upload the file originally I use storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {   prefs.setString('currentProfileImageURL', fileURL); }    So I just use the URL from the start instead of the location in the database.   So while this doesn't really answer this question, it's probably because there is no answer, I am doing it wrong.   Using the URL is working for me for now so hopefully this still works when I start having whole lists of images to maintain and manage in the application.

Comment: The main question here is, can I use these URL links in the database to delete these images too.    That's where the big unknown comes into play and why I opted originally to use the direct database path.   But maybe I can do everything I need to do using the URL instead.

Comment: check this article https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/05/06/using-firebase-storage-in-flutter/ (in the end there is a section regarding deleting)

Comment: yeah, it's not working in Flutter. It just shows the X instead of the actual image. And if you use the download URL into a browser, instead of displaying it (as you get with a pic uploaded on imgur), it just downloads it.

Comment: @EightRice probably there was some update in the firebase sdk..

Comment: @PeterHaddad here's the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379342/display-and-not-download-image-from-firebase-storage