# Display (and NOT download) image from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, flutter-web

This is an image uploaded to imgbb: https://i.ibb.co/Kj9bSGr/cogs.png
You will notice that clicking on it will display it in the browser.

This is an image uploaded to Firebase storage: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dorg-model.appspot.com/o/uploads%2Fwheeler.png?alt=media&token=ec11456d-7d83-4f1c-9352-36a6a699b718
When you access its address it just triggers a download.

After the setting the correct CORS policy and looking at available questions on this topic, I'm inclined to think that the reason my Flutter web app is not displaying the image is because of the above behavior.

I would like to get the image stored in Firebase to show up in the browser instead of triggering a download.

Comment: I hope this article will help you. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to the file type `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/png`. `application/octet-stream` is the default value when you upload to Firebase Storage.

### How to change to `image/png`

First, create a metadata object (or add to existing metadata) that has the field `contentType`

```
const metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/png',
};
```

Then, upload the file as you would normally, including the metadata as the 3rd argument.

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, file, metadata);
```

You can then use the download URL normally, showing the image instead of downloading it.

[Example in Firebase Docs of uploading with metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata)

[Example in Firebase Docs of adding metadata later](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata)

Note: If you use other file formats for images, you can use [these MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) for other image and file formats.

Comment: Hey thanks! The trouble is I'm using a Flutter web app, and the above code doesn't really work. Is there a way to set the default metadata for all objects in that storage? Cause I'm only sending pictures there.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work. Bounty is yours. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you issue is due to the file's type is application/octet-stream and not image/png

When I issue a GET to the link you posted I see in the response headers:
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Try changing the type to image/png and see if it solves your problem

Comment: Can I do that from the server side for all items in that bucket?